# upload.tool not used in custom boards.txt?

Tags: arduino-ide

I've created a custom board in `boards.txt` and changed the `upload.tool` to a nonsense value, and yet when I do an upload the IDE still calls `avrdude`.

For example, In boards.txt I've changed the line...

```
tile.upload.tool=avrdude
```

...to...

```
tile.upload.tool=nogood
```

...and added these lines to platform.txt...

```
# NOGOOD programmer

tools.nogood.cmd="dir"
tools.nogood.program.pattern="dir" 
tools.nogood.upload.pattern="dir"
```

...and reloaded the IDE and hit upload.. and it still runs AVRDUDE.

(Note that my board ID is `tile`)

I've verified that I am editing the correct boards.txt by changing the `cores` key to `nogood` and this does generate an error.

Is `boardid.upload.tool` not the right place to change the recipe called when upload is hit?

How/where does the `boardid.upload.tool=toolname` key in boards.txt get mapped to the `tools.toolname.upload.pattern` key in platforms.txt?

I am using Arduino IDE version 1.8.3.

The custom boards.txt is in the directory `Arduino\hardware\Move38\avr`.

This full custom platform package is here...

https://github.com/bigjosh/Move38-Arduino-Platform

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave the `protocol` unset in the `boards.txt`, then the current version of the Ardunio IDE (1.8.12) will then use the `program` recipe rather than the `upload` recipe in `platform.txt`. The `program` recipe can use the `{protocol}` key to get the programmer selected in the IDE menus.

Relevant source in Arduino IDE `SerialUploader.java`...

```
if (usingProgrammer || prefs.get("upload.protocol") == null) {
  return uploadUsingProgrammer(buildPath, className);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

From https://github.com/bigjosh/Move38-Arduino-Platform#programmers:

> Since there is no bootloader in a tile, all code must be programmed rather than downloaded.

When you do an "Upload Using Programmer", the tool is specified in the `{programmerID}.program.tool` property in programmers.txt. The `{boardID}.upload.tool` value is only used for a standard upload.

Since programmers.txt is not in your hardware package, this makes it very inconvenient to customize. What's worse is that the platform.txt associated with the selected programmer is used, rather than the one in your hardware package, for "Upload Using Programmer". For this reason, [some popular hardware packages include their own copies](https://github.com/MCUdude/MightyCore/commit/777c5d6a373180c36d08c885c66690ccf2bd5a09#diff-d277425b7f2c4e00ec2a6a653169aa21) of all standard programmers. The downside of this is it really clutters up the **Tools > Programmer** menu if you have multiple of these packages installed.

Comment: Ugg. So ugly. Thanks for the authoritative answer - these are hard to come by in Arduino land! :)

Comment: For future lookers, it does not seem like the `{boardID}.upload.tool` in `platform.txt` is *always* used for a standard upload. For example, it does not seem to be used if an `upload.speed` is not specified in `boards.txt` (even if the specified tool does not have a baudrate). It also does not seem to be used on OSX sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Custom tools for the Arduino build process are documented in the Boards Manager Package Index spec here...

https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.6.x-package_index.json-format-specification#tools-definitions

So it would seem that it i not possible to use custom tools with a manually installed board since there is no package index file.

Comment: This problem does not appear to be limited to only custom tools, it also seems to happen with built in tools like `avrdude`. :/