# Adding a custom board to the Arduino IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, samd21g, custom

I would like to know what is the procedure for adding a custom board to the Arduino IDE?

My custom board is similar to the Arduino Zero. Instead of using the ATSAMD21G18, my board is based around the ATSAMC21G18. I also have the Atmel/Microchip SAMC21 Xplained development board.

I have found some open source code where the author has adapted/forked the Arduino SAMD21 code and made it work for the SAMC21 Xplained board ([here](https://github.com/prices/ArduinoCore-samd)). The author has stuck to the [Arduino hardware folder structure](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-3rd-party-Hardware-specification) and has added the SAMC21 Xplained to the `board.txt` file.

As a test, when I install the Arduino SAMD21 from the Arduino Board Manager, I noticed that it installed the hardware files in the following directory:

```
 %LOCALAPPDATA%\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\1.6.19\
```

I have read that to add hardware files to the board manager I need to create a `.json` file with the appropriate details. [More information here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.6.x-package_index.json-format-specification). However, as far as I can tell, this requires me to zip the SAMC21 hardware files into a [tarball](http://computing.help.inf.ed.ac.uk/FAQ/whats-tarball-or-how-do-i-unpack-or-create-tgz-or-targz-file) and provide a URL to that tarball. I also need to generate and insert a SHA in the `.json` file.

Am I on the right path with the `.json` file?

Or should I just download the SAMC21 hardware files and place them in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\samd\` folder next to the `1.6.19` folder?

My last resort would be to just copy the files into the existing SAMD21 hardware folder?

---

I have looked into the following Arduino SE questions but they do not answer the question satisfactorily.

- [upload.tool not used in custom boards.txt?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/43997/19409)
- [Arduino Due custom platform for school and library installation](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/45979/19409) (I would prefer not to use the Arduino IDE in portable mode.)

Comment: I think the .json file is just for publishing so the board manager can find it; you can edit boards.txt to add your own based on zero if its just for you.

Comment: do you want to publish it or only for your use? for your use it is simpler to add it into hardware subfolder of your sketches folder

Comment: @Juraj This would be just for my own use but I would need to replicate it on a couple of machines. I would appreciate if people could add answers for both scenarios.

Comment: @Juraj Thanks. I will look into the link shortly.

Answer (score 10):

The simplest clean way to add your board [using an existing core](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/platform-specification/#referencing-another-core-variant-or-tool) is to add the variant to your sketches folder's hardware subfolder. Only boards.txt and files for the board variant are added.

In your sketches folder create a 'hardware' folder. In this folder create a folder with the name of your boards package and a subfolder with the architecture name and a subfolder for variant and a name of the variant. for example `hardware/my_boards/samd/variants/samc21x`

In your variant folder (`variants/samc21x`) put the files for your variant based on variant files of the closet variant in the referenced hardware package. In your case perhaps a mkrzero would be a good example.

In your package's root (`hardware/my_boards/samd/`) add boards.txt file with entries for your board.

For boards.txt take the options for a similar board in referenced package. Change the names and settings and [prefix](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/latest/platform-specification/#referencing-another-core-variant-or-tool) `build.core` value with the name of the vendor of the referenced package. For arduino/samd it would be `arduino:`. For example `samc21x.build.core=arduino:arduino`

My custom and customized boards definitions https://github.com/jandrassy/my_boards

Comment: and `samc21x.build.extra_flags=-D__SAMC21G18A__ {build.usb_flags}` or similar. the Arduino SAMD core supports compilation for SAMC

Comment: success story: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=602377.msg4089655#msg4089655