# Arduino core libraries

Tags: library, arduino-zero

We have worked with a company to design a custom board based on the Arduino Zero and have also had them do some programming for us.

In doing so, they have had to modify the following Arduino core libraries:  variant.cpp, variant.h and wiring_analog.c.

Unfortunately, this causes problems with other projects using Arduino.

Is there a way to keep these libraries local to specific projects without modifying the original files?

Comment: you want to use the Arduino SAMD core with your board? create a board package which references the SAMD core

Comment: I'm wondering why they didn't define a new board type and use conditional compiling in the first place so that you could just use the new/modified files for everything.

Comment: for a mass sold board create a boards package for Boards Manager installation.  For a customized board or a small series put the files in the hardware folder https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/adding-a-custom-board-to-the-arduino-ide/60660#60660

Comment: @Juraj - Yes, we are using the Arduino SAMD core (Arduino Zero Native USB).  I will check out the link you provided.  Thank you.

Comment: it would be better to avoid the change in wiring_analog.c. what change is it?

Comment: @Juraj - I am not sure what changes were made.  I have sent an email to the Software Engineer to inquire.  I'll report back when I know.