# pin numbering for non-standard chips

Tags: pins

so i replaced the mainboard in (what was) an anet a8 3d printer with a proper RAMPS setup. there was nothing wrong with it, (or at least it wasnt damaged, there are a number of severe design flaws) so i thought it might be a good start point for a remote controlled crawler/bot thing. it already has four a4988 drivers on board, plus a few mosfets and other bits which will be great for accessories (planning headlights, horn, maybe light sensor). its built around the atmega1284p, which is something of an oddball inbetween the 328 on the uno and the 2560 on the mega, but is the same product line. ive already worked out the libraries/drivers for the ch340 or whatever it is that is needed to flash code to the board,**it already has already been added to the arduino ide**, i have successfully flashed sketches to it before, but not my own. what im wondering is how to declare pins when im writing my own code. the bottom right of [this](https://ibb.co/5LG643b) schematic lists connections to the main chip, is it reasonably safe to assume that the digital pin numbers listed there can be used like the normally labeled headers on a standard board? how exactly are those numbers determined?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a custom board to the Arduino IDE](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/adding-a-custom-board-to-the-arduino-ide)

Comment: example https://github.com/jandrassy/my_boards

Comment: Each chip uses the normal register names (like PORTB or DDRA) with the bits representing a pin. The pin numbers, that you know from other Arduinos are just referencing to them. The numbers are defined in the core for the used chip. So when you are installing the core for the used chip inside the Arduino IDE, that core also defines the pin numbers.

Comment: @Juraj a custom board file has already been made by someone, it sounds like i need to dig through those core files to find where things get enumerated or whatever the word is

Comment: not much digging. it is the variants folder. in my_boards I have a custom 1284p too

Comment: Look for a file named `pins_arduino.h`.

Answer (score 1):

ok so what ive found is that pins are declared in a file, `pins_arduino.h`. for each board/chip/variant another file is added(or created, if writing your own) to the arduino hardware files. in my specific case the numbers in the graphic are consistent with those listed in the hardware file, so im good