# Accessing Physical Pins in Arduino Due from Arduino IDE

Tags: pins, pinmode

It is possible to access the Physical Pin 93, Pin PC11 on ATSAM3X8E in [Arduino Due](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMappingSAM3X)  from the Arduino IDE?

I am programming a Barebone ATSAM3X8E, and it do not seems to be allocated by [Arduino Due](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/due-pinout-diagram/129258) nor by ATSAM3X8E for any other purpose than the PC Port.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: you can configure your own board for Arduino IDE https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/adding-a-custom-board-to-the-arduino-ide/60660#60660

Answer (score 1):

## Modifying/Making a variant

If you wanted to do it in an Arduino-like way it would require editing the Arduino Due [variant.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/blob/c43d4be/variants/arduino_due_x/variant.cpp) or copying the making your own variant, say from a copy of the Due, and editing the `extern const PinDescription g_APinDescription[]` array to include an entry that matches for PC11.

### Example changes

As an experiment I made the following changes to files in the `packages/arduino/hardware/sam/1.6.12/variants/arduino_due_x` under the arduino15 directory.

In variant.cpp, an entry for in the `g_APinDescription` array is insert an index number 79, between the existing two entries (shown for context):

```c
  { PIOB, PIO_PB23B_SPI0_NPCS3,ID_PIOB,PIO_PERIPH_B,PIO_DEFAULT, PIN_ATTR_DIGITAL,                  NO_ADC, NO_ADC, NOT_ON_PWM,  NOT_ON_TIMER }, // NPCS3
  // Addition line here VVVV (this is the line for PC12, copied with PIO_PC12 changed to PIO_PC11
  { PIOC, PIO_PC11,          ID_PIOC, PIO_OUTPUT_0, PIO_DEFAULT, PIN_ATTR_DIGITAL,                  NO_ADC, NO_ADC, NOT_ON_PWM,  NOT_ON_TIMER }, //
  // 79 .. 84 - "All pins" masks

  // 79 - TWI0 all pins
  { PIOA, PIO_PA17A_TWD0|PIO_PA18A_TWCK0, ID_PIOA, PIO_PERIPH_A, PIO_DEFAULT, (PIN_ATTR_DIGITAL|PIN_ATTR_COMBO), NO_ADC, NO_ADC, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER },
```

This is a copy of the entry for PC12, with `PIO_PC12` changed to `PIO_PC11`.

In variant.h, `PINS_COUNT` changes to `80u`, because we've inserted  the pin:

```c
#define PINS_COUNT           (80u)
```

and later in the file the pin number associate with CAN are bumped up by one also because they're all numbered after the point of insertion:

```c
/*
 * Complementary CAN pins
 */
static const uint8_t CAN1RX = 89;
static const uint8_t CAN1TX = 90;

// CAN0
#define PINS_CAN0            (91u)
// CAN1
#define PINS_CAN1            (92u)
```

I programmed a sketch the blinks PC11 by way of `digitalWrite(79, state);` and carefully placed a logic probe on the the unrouted pin on the Due board, and it "blinks" just fine.  That's as far as I've tested.

## Direct control

Alternately you could control the pin in your code manually, doing what `digitalWrite` or `digitalRead` would normally do.  In other words, you could read the description of something like digitalWrite [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-sam/blob/c43d4be431bd5673f6bb26f83411bbd8f9ef89ef/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L91) and substitute all of the references that it would have gotten from `g_APinDescription` with hard-coded values.

Comment: If I get a chance I will try altering the variant here.  It looks like the new pin would have to be inserted before the `PINS_COUNT` index, which would need to be made larger by one.  And then `PINS_COUNT` and a few other named values for pins would have to change to reflect all their indices increasing by one.

Comment: I made the six line changes indicated, for some reason the 93 physical pin, PC11, in our sketch at 79, it stays at 3.3V. I will keep trying

Comment: You remember to `pinMode(79, OUTPUT);` ?

Comment: Yes... as all other pins. As reference, it is the 93 physical pin in ATSAM3X8E, it is located close to the A0 connector, in the Arduino Due board.

Comment: I gather from the that and the update that you're concern we're not talking about the same pin, but I'm pretty sure we are.  Here is [the contact I'm making](https://imgur.com/a/nUdFbaO) to probe.

Comment: Right... perhaps i am omitting some step. I will keep checking.