# How to modify an Arduino Due native USB port VID and PID?

Tags: usb, arduino-due

I would like to know if it is possible to modify the VID and PID of the Native USB port of an Arduino Due.

Comment: in `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\arduino\hardware\sam\<version>\boards.txt`. but better create a custom definition [this way](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/54484/adding-a-custom-board-to-the-arduino-ide/60660#60660)

Comment: No wait, probably I did not write it correctly. I would like to set up the native USB to have a different VID or PID from the current one VID_03EB PID_6124.

Comment: the values from boards.txt are used in the USB handling part in the uploaded sketch